# Generalization Error and Matrix Factorizations?

Tags: model-selection, error, aic, bic, matrix-decomposition

This is more of a discussion/conceptual idea but:

**Is the notion of generalization error well-defined for a problem such as matrix factorization?**

I'm working with tensors/matrices and performing algorithms such as non-negative matrix factorizations etc.. It got me thinking:

1. Do standard AIC/BIC techniques makes sense in this context?
2. How can generalization apply if the data is somewhat "fixed" (we have final/desired matrix i.e. population data already defined, so what does it mean to generalize?).
3. How should number of dimensions, $D$, and number of samples $N$ be defined?

Adding to my confusion is that many algorithms allow one to define matrices and algorithms probabilistically, and we are often occupied with finding some notion of the "best" low-dim representation - a lot of **concepts paralleling basic model selection ideas**.

Comment: You can see an example in sention 5 of this paper.[Maximum-Margin Matrix Factorization](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2655-maximum-margin-matrix-factorization.pdf)